# How can I get data from a subchart with C3.js

Tags: charts, c3.js

I have to take the data from a subchart realized with the C3.js library to generate a table.

How can I get that data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onbrush` callback (http://c3js.org/reference.html#subchart-onbrush) to get the selected domain (and then, if required, use it to filter your data)

```
...
subchart: {
    onbrush: function (domain) { 
        // use domain (array) here
    }
    ...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvn4y0vv/

---

For instance, this is how you'd do it for a single series

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    },
    subchart: {
        show: true,
        onbrush: function (domain) {
            var filteredData = this.data()[0].values.filter(function (e, i) {
                return (e.x >= domain[0] && e.x <= domain[1])
            }).map(function (e) {
                return e.value;
            })

            // do something with filteredData
        }
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8dpnmvnq/

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really expert...how can I get the y values?